# What happens when you instantiate a new Object(1) with a parameter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

What happens when you call:

`new Object(1)`

When I tried it out, it returned:

```
[Number: 1]
```

I want to understand what is going on there. Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: How was `[String: 'a']` logged where input was `Number` `1`? Can you reproduce at [stacksnippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? or [plnkr](http://plnkr.co)?

Comment: `> var b = new Object(1)`
`> b`
`[Number: 1]`

Comment: @CairoStewart: So where did `'a'` come from?

Comment: my bad wrong example

Comment: `> var b = new Object("a")`
`undefined`
`> b`
`[String: 'a']`

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object `The Object constructor creates an object wrapper for the given value`

Comment: Yeah I was thinking, primitive types are objects right?

Comment: _"my bad wrong example"_ Perhaps consider updating Question to reflect this?

Comment: Exactly you get a String object wrapper for value passed "a".

Comment: *"primitive types are objects right?"* No. Primitive data types are Null, Undefined, String, Number, Boolean and Symbol. Object is its own data type. *Some* primitive types have an object equivalent. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look at the spec:

When [`new Object(arg)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-object-constructor) is invoked, we are essentially calling `ToObject(arg)`.

[`ToObject`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-toobject) is defined as

> The abstract operation ToObject converts argument to a value of type Object according to Table 13

And the table says:

> Number:   Return a new Number object whose `[[NumberData]]` internal slot is set to the value of argument. See [20.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-number-objects) for a description of Number objects.

So it's the same as calling `new Number(1)`, i.e. it creates a number object.

---

The *primitive data types* String, Number and Boolean have equivalent *object* values that can be created by invoking the equivalent constructor functions. But that is not a common thing to do since object values behave differently than primitive values, i.e. a number primitive will behave different than a number object in certain cases.

Example:

```
Boolean(0); // false
Boolean(new Number(0)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for the default constuctor:
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.2.1

> When the Object constructor is called with no arguments or with one
>   argument value, the following steps are taken:
>
> - If value is supplied, then
>
>   - If Type(value) is Object, then
>
>     - If the  value is a native ECMAScript object, do not create a new object but    simply return value.
>     - If the value is a host object, then actions are    taken and a result is returned in an implementation-dependent manner    that
>         may depend on the host object.
>   - If Type(value) is String, return ToObject(value).
>   - If Type(value) is Boolean, return ToObject(value).
>   - If Type(value) is Number, return ToObject(value).
> - Assert: The argument value was not supplied or its type was Null or Undefined.
> - Let obj be a newly created native ECMAScript object.
> - Set the  [[Prototype]] internal property of obj to the standard built-in Object prototype object (15.2.4).
> - Set the [[Class]] internal property    of obj to "Object". Set the [[Extensible]] internal property of obj    to true.
> - Set all the internal methods of obj as specified in 8.12.
> - Return obj.

Comment: Just FYI, the current spec is http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/, which doesn't contain that specific paragraph anymore.

Comment: Yep, that's what I have linked to in my answer. I'm just saying that the algorithm has changed and doesn't exist in the latest spec in that form.

Comment: I see.
I think the newest specification is backward compatible.